# Test Windows Phone 8 App on actual device

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to test my windows phone 8 app on an **actual device**, like Nokia Lumia 820 (NOT Simulator) before submitting to store? How?

(*Also I may need to create some applications just for myself, and not for sending to store... :)* )

Update: I saw that developers should pay for developer account to install their apps on their phones, but What about WP8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy your app from Visual Studio to the developer unlocked device. That means you need to have a Windows Phone Store account registered and the device associated with it. You can have up to 5 devices associated with an account.

Comment: if we register the device from one WP SDK then can we deploy application using another SDK. For example if my friend registers my phone under his account then can I deploy a test application from my PC?

Comment: Yes, you can. The phone is unlocked and you can deploy apps to it from any machine.

Answer (score 17):

You can test your app on any real device, you just need to have developer account to unlock your phone or phones for debugging.
It costs 99$ per year per developer, or you can get it for free if you are student using DreamSpark, or BizSpark, or you have MSDN or TechNet subscription.
[How to register your phone for development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
Once you have developer account, just start the Windows Phone Developer Registration tool, attach your phone to PC, unlock it and then you can select the Device in your project for debugging.

Comment: How many unsigned apps can I install on a developer unlocked phone? Is it limited?

Comment: I think it's 10. The goal of dev-unlocking your phone is not to install arbitrary number of apps, but only to use it for testing.

Comment: It's possible to get the number increased by contacting WP support. However usually you'll just uninstall the apps you're not working on so you won't hit the limit.

Comment: @MartinSuchan I want to use dev-unlocking for two purposes: testing, and creating some apps just for myself...

Comment: @dotMorten And what do they need for increasing that number? money? or what? (I want to use dev-unlocking for two purposes: testing, and creating some apps just for myself...)

Comment: Microsoft should have made the testing easier. At least they should allow 1 application. For personal interest/testing why do I have to spend $99!

Comment: How can i use my technet subscription to regester a dev account?

Answer (score 15):

You can **now register one phone without a developer account**, as you can see in the prerequisites of registering a phone:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

You only need to have a Microsoft account (**not** a developer account), to which you can register the phone you want to test on. Microsoft also changed the limitations on how many phones you can register with that developer account: they are only three by now. I did not find an official statement on these changes, but they must have been taken quite recently...

After you downloaded the WP 8 SDK from the Microsoft Download Center, go to "All Apps" on your computer and choose "Windows Phone Developer Registration".

Comment: This is the only valid answer now, it should be marked as correct. BTW it is great that this policy was improved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a Windows Phone developer account to deploy and test the App on your Phone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a live/outlook account and Windows Phone Developer Registration tool for unlocking the device to install the apps on the device. This tool is installed along with your Windows Phone SDK.

To install the app you need to unlock the device first, for this you need to connect your Windows Phone via USB to system and start the Registration tool. The tool detects the phone and asks you to login into your Microsoft account(live/outlook) , after this step the phone is successfully unlocked.

After unlocking the phone you can use visual studio or Windows Phone Power Tools or Application Deployment tool to install applications on the device.

Previously we need to have a developer account for installation of apps on devices but now a Microsoft Account(live/outlook) is enough for doing so.