# WP 8: How to deploy/export Application from Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

in android, we right click to our project, click export and get the apk.

For windows phone 8 , in visual studio 2012, how can i export my application into my desktop or somewhere ?

Anyone can help about it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Here is a thread with the same question and a good answear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669696/test-windows-phone-8-app-on-actual-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time when you build you project - Visual Studio builds XAP file, which is actual package for uploading it to Windows Phone Store or deploying to the real device. 
This may help [Submit your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206724%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

For Windows Phone you get a XAP file instead of an APK file.

The XAP in the ARM Release ie- `..\<Project Folder>\Bin\ARM\Release\` should be submitted to the Windows Store or Deployed to Device. Windows Phone Devices uses ARM based processors.

To generate the output-

- First Select Release from the Solution Configuration DropBox.
- Then go to configuration manager and change the AnyCPU field to ARM.
- Then Build the project.

To Run on Device-

- Open Application Deployment(a program that is installed with the
  Windows Phone SDK)
- Select Target Device(Phone should be connected by USB and Unlocked.
  For WP 7 you need Zune.)
- Browse and Select the XAP file in the `\Bin\ARM\Release\`
- Click Deploy Button

To Run on Emulator- (use AnyCPU Build Configuration)

- Open Application Deployment(a program that is installed with the
  Windows Phone SDK)
- Select Target emulator.
- Browse and Select the XAP file in the `\Bin\x86\Release\`
- Click Deploy Button

Answer (score 0):

After building your application with VS, If you want to deploy your app, simply go to your Windows SDK folder for instance *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0*

and open **XapDeploy.exe** under *Tools\XAP Deployment*

search for your *.xap file which is in your bin project's folder (for instance *C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\HTML5App1\Bin\Debug*)