# How to deploy Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime App (for evaluation)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

**SITUATION:** I have developed a Windows Phone 8.1 (Runtime) app. The app is ready for testing/evaluation and therefore I want some people to test my app. I like to send them the XAP-file which they can install via the `XapDeploy.exe` or `AppDeploy.exe` tool. (How you would do it with Android with APK-files).

According to [WP 8: How to deploy/export Application from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053787/wp-8-how-to-deploy-export-application-from-visual-studio) answer 3 there should be an .XAP file in `..\<Project Folder>\Bin\ARM\Release\` folder. But for me there isn't a file.

**WHAT I TRIED:** I have created an App Package ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx)). In that folder there are some files: APPX-files and an APPXSYM-file but no XAP file(s). With another [deployement tool](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24119.windows-phone-8-1-app-deployment-how-to-deploy-appx-file-with-application-development-tool.aspx) I can deploy APPX-files but this gives an error `code: 0x81030118`.

**Q:**
Why is there no XAP-file in my projectfolder (`..\<Project Folder>\Bin\ARM\Release\`)? This is maybe a WP8 file only, but why are the APPX-files giving me an error?

---

**UPDATE 1:** I've managed to remove the error and now the deployement tool gives status "App deployement complete.". But the next problem, the app doesn't show up in the phone app list...

**UPDATE 2:** Somehow my phone isn't developer unlocked anymore and I can't get it unlocked again.. Think that's causing the problems.

Comment: WinRT 8.1 projects don't build xaps, they build appxs. Only Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0/8.1 projects build xaps.

Comment: OK, but why is the APPX file deployement not working propperly? It said it is deployed but it didn't show up in the app list..

Comment: 0x81030118 means the device is not unlocked. so do a hard reset, reinstall the phone and try to unlock the phone now again

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I can reproduce the problem. It happens when I try to install the app via the tools of the WP8.1 SDKs, therefore it needed an update, where my phone reacted to by disabling the developer mode. It wouldn't unlock the phone here.

I followed this steps to get the phone working again:

1. Unplug the phone from the PC, close SDK programs.
2. Reset the phone (hard reset).
3. Reconnect to PC
4. Enable developer mode again.