# Remotely access Windows Phone 7 or 8 from desktop

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, remote-access

I am new to windows phone technology ,so I am trying to access windows phone 7 or 8 remotely from desktop. I have searched on many sites , but there are many solutions regarding remote desktop that means remotely handle desktop from mobile phones but I have not found any solutions in reverse manner i.e Windows Phone from desktop ,also there is many solutions are available for android phones but not even single solution for windows phone.So,is there any API or any other way for remotely handle windows phone.Any kind of help would greatly appreciated.

Thank u.

Comment: So, the question is basically about testing on real device. Have you checked <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669696/test-windows-phone-8-app-on-actual-device>?

Comment: Thanks Olter,but I don't want to deploy or test on actual device, ex. I am trying to access my phone from desktop which is on another place and my phone is on another place. how it will be possible ?

Comment: That's unlikely possible, in my opinion. Also, I don't think, that's a good question for stackoverflow. Maybe you should try to ask this on stackexchange -> windows-phone community.

Comment: but why is this so because we can control desktop remotely from mobile phone but we can not control windows phone from desktop.So is there any other way (out of box) for remotely control phones from desktop ?